# Cypher - how to walk graph while computing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm just starting studying Cypher here..
How would would I specify a Cypher query to return the node connected, from 1 to 3 hops away of the initial node, which has the highest average of weights in the path?

**Example**

Graph is: 
(I know I'm not using the Cypher's notation here..)

```
A-[2]-B-[4]-C
A-[3.5]-D
```

It would return D, because 3.5 > (2+4)/2

And with Graph:

```
A-[2]-B-[4]-C
A-[3.5]-D
A-[2]-B-[4]-C-[20]-E
A-[2]-B-[4]-C-[20]-E-[80]-F
```

It would return E, because (2+4+20)/3 > 3.5
and F is more than 3 hops away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to write the query, which has the benefit of being easy to read, is

```
MATCH p=(A {name: 'A'})-[*1..3]-(x)
UNWIND [r IN relationships(p) | r.weight] AS weight
RETURN x.name, avg(weight) AS avgWeight
  ORDER BY avgWeight DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Here we extract the weights in the path into a list, and unwind that list. Try inserting a RETURN there to see what the results look like at that point. Because we unwind we can use the `avg()` aggregation function. By returning not only the `avg(weight)`, but also the name of the last path node, the aggregation will be grouped by that node name. If you don't want to return the weight, only the node name, then change `RETURN` to `WITH` in the query, and add another return clause which only returns the node name.

You can also add something like `[n IN nodes(p) | n.name] AS nodesInPath` to the return statement to see what the path looks like. I created an example graph based on your question with below query with nodes named `A, B, C` etc.

```
CREATE (A {name: 'A'}),
       (B {name: 'B'}),
       (C {name: 'C'}),
       (D {name: 'D'}),
       (E {name: 'E'}),
       (F {name: 'F'}),
(A)-[:R {weight: 2}]->(B),
(B)-[:R {weight: 4}]->(C),
(A)-[:R {weight: 3.5}]->(D),
(C)-[:R {weight: 20}]->(E),
(E)-[:R {weight: 80}]->(F)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and example. Two extra questions, if I may: if I'm only interested in the highest average, is there a way I could use max() (would it have better performance?)?; and, if I wan to use a custom function instead of avg(), how would I do?

Answer (score 0):

1) To select the possible paths with length from one to three - use match with [`variable length relationships`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels):

```
MATCH p = (A)-[*1..3]->(T)
```

2) And then use the [`reduce function`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) to calculate the average weight. And then sorting and limits to get one value:

```
MATCH p = (A)-[*1..3]->(T)
WITH p, T, 
     reduce(s=0, r in rels(p) | s + r.weight)/length(p) AS weight
RETURN T ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `length(p)` rather than `length(o)`? Also, need a property on A in the MATCH clause to anchor the path.

Comment: thank you stodb; question: isn't it (A {name: 'A'}) necessary, as in jjaderberg answer?

Comment: @JoãoOtero Yes, it means that you know how to choose the starting node (A) - by name, or other props.